# Python lists and list item matches - can my code/reasoning be improved?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

query level: beginner

As part of a learning exercise I have written code that must check if a string (as it is build up through raw_input) matches the beginning of any list item and if it equals any list item.

```
wordlist = ['hello', 'bye'] 
handlist = [] 
letter = raw_input('enter letter: ') 
handlist.append(letter) 
hand = "".join(handlist) 
for item in wordlist: 
    if item.startswith(hand): 
        while item.startswith(hand): 
            if hand not in wordlist: 
                letter = raw_input('enter letter: ') 
                handlist.append(letter) 
                hand = "".join(handlist) 
            else: break 
        else: break 
print 'you loose'
```

This code works but how can my code (and my reasoning/approach) be improved?
I have the feeling that my nesting of `IF`, `WHILE` and `FOR` statements is overkill.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Dave, I was able to considerably shorten and optimise my code.

```
wordlist = ['hello','hamburger', 'bye', 'cello']
hand = ''
while any(item.startswith(hand) for item in wordlist):
    if hand not in wordlist:
        hand += raw_input('enter letter: ')
    else: break
print 'you loose'
```

I'm surprised my original code worked at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the `handlist` variable; you can just concatenate the value of `raw_input` with `hand`.

You can save the first `raw_input` by starting the `while` loop with `hand` as an empty string since every string has `startswith("")` as `True`.

Finally, we need work out best way to see if any of the items in `wordlist` starts with `hand`.  We could use a list comprehension for this:

```
[item for item in wordlist if item.startswith(hand)]
```

and then check the length of the returned list if greater than zero.

However, even better, python has [the `any()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) which is perfect for this: it returns `True` if any element of an iterable is `True`, so we just evaluate `startswith()` for each member of `wordlist`.

Putting this all together we get:

```
wordlist = ['hello', 'bye'] 
hand = ""

while any(item.startswith(hand) for item in wordlist):
    hand += raw_input('enter letter: ')  
print 'you loose'
```

Comment: +1 for any. Didn't know that. (*learn something new today* - check)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - there's `all()` too: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all

Comment: I'll spare that one for tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi Dave. That's great thanks! So strings, just like lists, dictionaries and tuples, can also be populated. and it makes the "".join() part redundant. Thank You! I will rework my code and post it to see if it's any good. Although you're pretty close to what i had.